# Is there a way to fix the thickness of hrule?

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-spacing

Latex keeps adjusting the thickness of

```
\hrule
```

and I believe it may be due to the vspaces around it, i.e. I am using the following section demarkation in my resume

```
\hrule
\vspace{-0.4em}
\subsection*{\textsc{Teaching Experience}}
\vspace{0.6em}
\hrule
\vspace{0.6em}
```

And that results in some sections that have the lower line (under which text follows) thinner sometimes.

Is there a way to make this consistent?

Moreover, I am using a template and can someone explain to me what negative space is? I don't understand why the author of the original file uses it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The rules so produced are all 0.4pt thick. You can experience optical artifacts when previewing the output, because the screen has a coarse resolution and can only paint an integer number of pixels. Try magnifying and the rules will appear all with the same thickness.

Comment: Thanks so much @egreg oh really? Because what happened was that I uploaded it to a webform and then redownloaded it as a sanity check to make sure I uploaded the right doc and discovered some lines to be thinner?!

Comment: Producing a PNG at coarse resolution is similar to previewing on screen.

Comment: @egreg Ah sweet thanks so much! Man was I worried so close before the deadline. Also, could you explain the addendum, why the author of the original uses negative vspaces?

Comment: Probably because he/she doesn't know how `\hrule` works. `;-)` The purpose is apparently to adjust the spacing.

Comment: @egreg oh boy haha. How would I use it correctly then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At coarse resolutions, rules can appear to differ in thickness, because of rounding to pixels. Those rules are exactly 0.4pt thick, because that's the default value when no `height` or `depth` keywords accompanied by a dimension follow.

For instance at a resolution where 0.4pt doesn't correspond to an integral number of pixels, the viewer will round them and the rule can appear thicker or thinner, depending on its position on the pixel grid. When you have doubts about this, always look at maximum magnification, which will make pixel rounding negligible. Also a printout, say at 600dpi or better, would help in removing the doubt.

Making a PNG will not help, unless it is produced with a rather high resolution: the problem is the same, that is, pixel rounding. A pixel is either white or black (or colored, that's the same issue).

Note that the method of surrounding a title with rules is not the best possible, because it allows a page break between the rules and the section title. It would be better to use a package such as `titlesec` for doing the job in a cleaner way.